How can calculate length or coordinate of any molecule in different quantum state [like (rotational quantum state)j=2] with any software or code?
How can one determine the bond length of a diatomic or tri-atomic molecule(rot. state J=3 and vib. state v=2) from its ground state bond length (x angstrom) using computational tools or programming code?

Please check this post agin. and please try to give the answer this question or give any idea to solve this related theory and concept.
